# GDB sets multiple breakpoints when I am unambiguously setting a breakpoint for a line number. Bad debug symbols?

Tags: gcc, gdb, breakpoints, debug-symbols, gcc4

I get this strange behaviour when setting a breakpoint:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.2 (Debian 7.6.2-1)
... Blah blah legal stuff
Reading symbols from /home/matt/Programming/Latium/latium/src/test_latium...done.
(gdb) break base58.h:144
Breakpoint 1 at 0x43597f: base58.h:144. (6 locations)
(gdb) info breakpoints
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
1       breakpoint     keep y   <MULTIPLE>         
1.1                         y     0x000000000043597f in CBase58Data::SetString(char const*) at base58.h:144
1.2                         y     0x0000000000452fcf in CBitcoinAddress::CBitcoinAddress(char const*) at /home/matt/Programming/Latium/latium/src/base58.h:144
1.3                         y     0x000000000045324f in CBitcoinSecret::SetString(char const*) at /home/matt/Programming/Latium/latium/src/base58.h:144
1.4                         y     0x00000000004db613 in DecodeAddress(std::string, CService&) at base58.h:144
1.5                         y     0x0000000000573d1a in CBitcoinAddress::CBitcoinAddress(std::string const&) at base58.h:144
1.6                         y     0x00000000005bea68 in ReadKeyValue(CWallet*, CDataStream&, CDataStream&, int&, std::vector<uint256, std::allocator<uint256> >&, bool&, bool&, std::string&, std::string&) at base58.h:144
```

That happens to be 6 lines, none of which is the actual line I want, ie. line 144 of base58.h. What could cause this and how can I determine the problem and fix it?

I have GNU Make 3.81. I'm using -j8 if that makes any difference. gcc is Debian 4.8.2-16.

I tried setting breakpoints in other files and they appear to work, including other header files. I also tried cleaning the makefile... No luck. I tried clearing ccache... No luck either.

Comment: Likely you have breakpointed something which ends up in multiple places in the compiled code as a result of inclusion in multiple source files.

Comment: If you are trying to set a breakpoint in a template, GDB will have to create breakpoints at every location where the template is instantiated.  It has to do something similar for inline functions.

Comment: Inline functions are not an issue in other files, because I've tried. I also tried setting a breakpoint in a method and that failed. So even though the breakpoint in this example is in an inlined function, that isn't the problem. This is not a template either.

Comment: If it's to do with inclusion in multiple source files, then why do other header files work?

Comment: It depends on whether the function has actually been inlined.  Perhaps the compiler decided not to inline functions from that other header.  You can find out for sure by examining the DWARF.

Answer (score 1):

It's silly of me now that I think of it, but when I looked again the makefile included -02 in the compiler flags. Obviously if you use optimisation your debug symbols become useless, so never use optimisation for debug builds.

Comment: I strongly disagree. Everything that I debug these days is fully optimized (due to the nature of the code). You just have to debug it as the assembly level and consider the line numbers in the debug symbols hints as to what *probably* caused the particular assembly instruction.

Comment: It's not useless, but it becomes harder.